# prettier-plugin-sort-imports import order

Tags: typescript, react-native, import

Hello stackoverflow so I'm using the package trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports

https://github.com/trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports

I currently have a import order that looks like

```
import React from "react";

import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import SideMenuContent from "../sideMenu/SideMenu";
import HeaderButton from "../header/HeaderButton";
import LandingScreen from "../landing/LandingScreen";
import Theme from "../../themes/styles";
import { AptosColors } from "../../themes/interfaces";
import Header from "../header/Header";
import a from "@aaa-scp/demo"
import { b } from "@aaa-scp/demo2"
import { DrawNavigatorParams, INITIAL_ROUTE } from "./DrawNavigatorParams";
import { useWindowDimensions } from "react-native";
```

The expected import order I am trying to achieve is

```
import React from "react";
import { useWindowDimensions } from "react-native";
import a from "@aaa-scp/demo"
import { b } from "@aaa-scp/demo2"
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import Theme from "../../themes/styles";
import { AptosColors } from "../../themes/interfaces";
import HeaderButton from "../header/HeaderButton";
import LandingScreen from "../landing/LandingScreen";
import SideMenuContent from "../sideMenu/SideMenu";
import Header from "../header/Header";
import menu from "./menu"
```

Basically the idea here is that I want to import react, react-native,  then the node modules package "@react-navigation/drawer" or other node-modules packages, @aaa-scp then files that are structurally in other nested folders until the folder is only 1 level deep or in the same directory. How can I achieve this by populating the `importOrder` array in my prettierrc.js file. I've read the documentation but I can't seem to get the right importOrder pattern. Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

With my importOrder array empty I am getting this. As you can see its grabbing the nested directory imports first which is not what I want.

```
import { AptosColors } from "../../themes/interfaces";
import Theme from "../../themes/styles";
import Header from "../header/Header";
import HeaderButton from "../header/HeaderButton";
import LandingScreen from "../landing/LandingScreen";
import SideMenuContent from "../sideMenu/SideMenu";
import { DrawNavigatorParams, INITIAL_ROUTE } from "./DrawNavigatorParams";
import a from "@aaa-scp/demo"
import { b } from "@aaa-scp/demo2"
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import React from "react";
import { useWindowDimensions } from "react-native";
```

Comment: Show what you've tried in pettierrc file